# How can I add an item to the trade window?

Tags: pc, dungeon-defenders

All I can figure out how to do is add mana to the trade screen. So I can trade mana for mana. That seems pointless. How do I trade items?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you open up the forge, on the menu on the right side at the top is a button that says "Add to trade" that will automatically add it to your trade window.

Comment: I tried looking where you said but I still couldn't find the button. Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: @StrixVaria I believe you need to have an active trade session with someone open first before you can actually add items to the trade window. The trade session remains open even if you close the trade window, which allows you to go between the forge and the trade window freely.

Comment: @TheQ I'll try that out next time I play with some friends. The UI on this game is really terrible. I'm learning to cope with it bit by bit.

Comment: @StrixVaria I struggled with the trade window for quite some time too.